# TV series about armored / mech-driving men

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

When I was a kid, I used to watch a series that I really liked, but I can't remember much about it anymore. The key parts I do remember:

- I saw it in the mid 90's on Dutch television. It was an American series, but I don't know when it aired originally and if the Dutch airing was in synch.
- It featured a team of four or five men, wearing some sort of modular armor. Their armor was brightly colored, there was a green dude, an orange dude ...
- The armor allowed them to connect into vehicles; I can clearly remember a motorcycle with side-mounted cannons. I believe one of them had an airplane-rig.
- I'm a bit unsure about the setting. Definitely futuristic and sci-fi.

Any idea what series this was?

Comment: was the protagonist martians?

Comment: Was it possibly [_The Centurions_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centurions_(TV_series))? The heroes had kind of modular bolt-on armour that combined in various configurations to give them different capabilities (there was definitely a jet, a motorbike and a submarine, amongst others). As the armour attached they would shout out "Power Xtreme!" (sic).

Comment: Could be M.A.S.K. Crime-fighters use special helmets to transform their vehicles into crime-fighting super-vehicles - including a flying car. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2Z1yLO9C-Q

Comment: @delinear Yes, it's the centurions! Make it an answer, so I can award you the rep.

Comment: @steenbergh consider it done, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like [*The Centurions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centurions_(TV_series)).

The show was released originally in 1986. It featured first three and later five Heroes who wore modular armour, *exo-frames*, that allowed them to fuse with various vehicles and weapon systems.

The team consisted of:

- *Max Ray* (Sea Operations Commander) who wore green.
- *Jake Rockwell* (Land Operations Specialist) who wore yellow.
- *Ace McCloud* (Air Operations Expert) who wore blue.
- *Rex Charger* (Energy Programmer) who wore red and green.
- *John Thunder* (Infiltration Commander) who wore black.

Their equipment includes, amongst many others:

> Wild Weasel - A protective armour assault weapon system in the shape of a motorcycle with a head shield and protective back shell for dangerous missions such as heavy forests or rocky terrains. It has battle modes including tracking, anti-aircraft, high speed travel and land attack. It's weapons include two land lasers and a front assault pack module for storing accessories.